# How to add CSS on specific cell in syncfusion grid grouping control in css

Tags: css, events, grid, syncfusion

I want to add custom cssClass on a specific column. But my code below works in the GridRowData Bound event, but does not work in the GridHeaderRowDataBound event. How can I add a CSS class in  GridHeaderRowDataBound event, please?

GridRowDataBound Event:

```
public void Entity_GridRowDataBound(object sender, Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.RowDataBoundEventArgs e, AHS.Security.Screen screen, int objectID)
    {
        switch (screen.ID)
        {
            case 3489://Expiring Agreements
                e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hideColumn";
                break;

        }
    }
```

GridHeaderRowDataBound Event:

```
     public void Entity_GridHeaderRowDataBound(object sender, Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.RowDataBoundEventArgs e, AHS.Security.Screen screen, Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.GridTableDescriptor tdescriptor)  
        {
        switch (screen.ID)
        {
            case 3489:
                e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hideColumn";

                tdescriptor.Columns[9].HeaderText = "  ";
                tdescriptor.Columns[9].Name = "  ";
                tdescriptor.Columns[9].MappingName = "  ";
                break;

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have event called headerRowDataBound .You can change the header css using this below code

```
this.GridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[0].Appearance.ColumnHeaderCell.CssClass = "MyClass";
this.GridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[0].HeaderText = "MyHeader";
this.GridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[0].MappingName = "Header";
```